# Is there a Risk World Championship?

Tags: risk, tournament

Is there any national or world level governing body that holds an annual Championship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Risk Tournament of Champions celebrated their 20th championship in 2008, the 2009 championship was [cancelled](http://www.conquerclub.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=105236).  The web page @ risktoc.org is defunct. You can view the old web pages via [The Internet Archive Wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20080613195150/http://www.risktoc.org/).

The replacement is the new [Annual Risk Classic](http://www.annualriskclassic.com/index.php).  The 1st championship will be decided November 6-7, 2010.